# Creating a Theme Customization File for October CMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I am having trouble getting theme customization form fields to show up in the backend when I use a separate theme customization file.  This is what I did.  In my theme.yaml file -- I have the following code:  `form: config/fields.yaml`.  That works to get the customization button to show up in the backend.

However, I'm not 100% sure how to format the config/fields.yaml file.  Currently, this is how I have it set up:

```
form:
  fields:
    layout:
      label: Layout
      comment: Choosed between a boxed or wide layout.
      type: dropdown
      options:
        stretched: Stretched
        boxed: Boxed
```

But nothing shows up.

I tried taking out the 'form:' -- still nothing shows up.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the "form:" in fields.yaml and reindent all.

```
form:
  fields:
    layout:
      label: Layout
      comment: Choosed between a boxed or wide layout.
      type: dropdown
      options:
        stretched: Stretched
        boxed: Boxed
```

```
fields:
  layout:
    label: Layout
    comment: Choosed between a boxed or wide layout.
    type: dropdown
    options:
      stretched: Stretched
      boxed: Boxed
```

This should work! Indentation is critical to proper interpretation of YAML

Comment: Thanks -- that did it.  Much appreciated.